# How can I view steam purchase history when you don't have money in your account?

Tags: steam

I'd like to view mine but I currently don't have any money on my account.

Answer (score 6):

You can view your account history here: https://store.steampowered.com/account/history/

To find it yourself, when logged into Steam, in the upper right click your account name and click *Account Details*. From here click *View Purchase History* in the *Store & Purchase History* section.